# logo not appearing in media print - IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, less

I have been trying to solve this for 2 hours now but no luck. The `less` code snippet works fine in all browsers except IE8. I checked IE8 supports `:after` and `:before`

I'm using standard IE8 doctype, using HTML5 shiv and also not running this in compatibility mode?

```
@media print {
      .app-header .large-header {

                    .logo span,
                    h1,
                    .action-links {
                        display: none;
                    }

                    .logo:before {
                        content: url('images/logo.png');
                        position:absolute;
                        top:0;
                        left:0;
                        width:150px;
                        height:28px;
                    }
                }
}
```

**UPDATE**

**Issue is that IE8 doesn't support printing content url. The workaround is to use an image instead.**

Answer (score 0):

IE8 does not support media queries this: `@media print {}` is not supported.

create a separate css for IE8 and in the HTML put a conditional like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style-ie.css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

See for yourself https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530813(v=VS.85).aspx

> Dynamic HTML (DHTML) expressions can be used in place of the preceding
>   value(s). As of Windows Internet Explorer 8, expressions are not
>   supported in IE8 Standards mode. For more information, see About
>   Dynamic Properties.

Comment: "media print is definitely supported in IE8. It is working and picking up all the styles except logo. The issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Having an extra print stylesheet or the print styles inside the main stylesheet won't cause issues on IE8.
What's an issue is that IE8 won't be able to display the logo when it's implemented using an `:before` pseudo-class.

Apart from that I always opt for an IE8 specific stylesheet, too, in order to overwrite stuff not working in this browser (if I have to support it at all).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about your markup but is it an option to remove the background image of the logo and use an actual `<img>` tag for it?

That way you would not need to change a lot of styles for printing pages. You should also keep in mind that there are a lot of printers out there, which disable background-imagery and background-colors by default!